# New to LibVLC - Trying out libVLC on VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libvlc

I downloaded vlc-2.2.4-win32.7z and extracted the files. I created an empty project in VS2010 and create a cpp file using the code I found on https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/

On VS2010 project property, I added the include file folder and added Linker library folder and libvlc.lib, libvlccore.lib, vlc.lib, vlccore.lib to additional dependencies.

I got this build error --> D:\VLC\vlc-2.2.4\sdk\lib\vlccore.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x16.

I have re-downloaded the file and still having the same error. Is there anything that I had done wrong .

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: You are probably mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: drescherjm - Thanks for the reply but everything has been set up to Win32.

Comment: For some reasons, the later versions do not work. I downloaded 2.1.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, the later versions do not work. I downloaded 2.1.3 and it worked.

Comment: It may be that this was built using an incompatible compiler. Visual Studio 2010 is just over 7 years old..